# Django multiple exists() aggregate

Tags: django, case, aggregate, models, exists

```
class Order(models.Model):
      # Some fields..
      status = models.IntegerField()
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

the status field can get four values: 1,2,3,4

I want to perform a query which will return a **single** row (tuple), with an indicator, according to:

```
if in the queryset there is a row with status=1, return 1  
elif there's row with status=3, return 3  
elif there's row with status=4, return 4  
elif there's row with status=2, return 2
```

In this priority (i.e, in this order, similar to how switch-case works).
I query them for a specific user to display some status message. So it should start somewhat like this:

```
Order.objects.filter(user=request.user) # ...? .aggregate() maybe ?
```

And I only need the indicator, not any Order objects.
I think in the db level it goes to something like `Case`, but I couldn't get that to work with django.

EDIT: to explain better, I could do it like that

```
if Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, status=1).exists():
   return 1
elif Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, status=3).exists():
   return 3
elif Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, status=4).exists():
   return 4
elif Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, status=2).exists():
   return 2
```

But obviously I want to avoid doing 4 queries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
order_statuses = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('status', flat=True)
```

This will return you the list of statuses. Now you can check as:

```
if 1 in order_statuses:
    return 1
elif 2 in order_statuses:
    return 3
elif 3 in order_statuses:
    return 4
elif 4 in order_statuses:
    return 2
```

This way you'll do your computation on your Django server instead on increasing the additional load on your Database.

Answer (score 3):

```
Order.objects.annotate(order_status=models.Case(
     models.When(status=1, then=0),
     models.When(status=3, then=1),
     models.When(status=4, then=2),
     models.When(status=2, then=3),
     default=models.F('status'),
     output_field=models.IntegerField(),
),).aggregate(models.Min('order_status'))
```

And need some dict for mapping statuses

Comment: I prefer not relying on the numeric value of the field. Second, this does not work, as if rows with status=3, and status=2 exists, 3 should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
# This will return a value of None, if no matching Order object exists,
# or the lowest status that exists:
return Order.objects.filter(
    user=request.user
).order_by(
   'status'
).values_list(
    'status', flat=True
).first()
```